# A question in Isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

Let G be a cyclic group. Soppose G and G' are isomorphic groups. Show that G' is also cyclic.

Can Someone Solve this pleaase? I have an exam 2 hours later!

Comment: [Cyclic group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group).

Comment: I have really read this both on wikipedia and on my textbook. But I don't understand very well.. Maybe if you solve this question, i'll understand what it means..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a group $G$ of order $n$ is cyclic, then that is equivalent to saying that there exists an element $g \in G$ such that $g^n = e$, where $n$ is the smallest natural number such that this holds.

(Note that $e$ is the identity element)

Comment: AND that for every $h \in G$, $h=g^k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @wckronholm your condition is not needed.

Comment: Ah. I did not see that you were assuming already the group has order $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Put differently, a group $G$ is cyclic if it can be generated by a single one of its elements.  If $G$ is our group, and $g$ is a generator element of $G$, then for any other $g' \in G$ we have that $g = (g')^k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.  We can also write this as $G = \left\langle g \right\rangle$.